# How to normalize the compass input?

Tags: javascript, mathematical-optimization

I want to rotate the compass image according to the degrees I receive. The input degrees are between 0 and 359 so when I rotate -1 degree from 0 , the image rotates one complete round and sets on 359:

```
function setCompass(degrees){
    $("#compass").stop().transition({rotate: -1*degrees +'deg'});
}
```

I tried to solve the problem by going back to **-1** instead of **359** so I changed the code to the following:

```
function setCompass(degrees){
    if (degrees>180){degrees=degrees-360}
    $("#compass").stop().transition({rotate: -1*degrees +'deg'});
}
```

It solved the lag on 0 and 360 but the problem was shifted to 180. Now when I rotate the device from 180 to 181, it rotates a complete negative round to go back to -179 ! Please suggest me how to modify the calculations so I get smooth changes on every degree?

Comment: you should introduce the current degrees/position of compass to your equation and take the shortest way (just measure the difference and take the samller one, so its either -x or +x degrees), hope this helps

Comment: Could you add the `jquery-transit`  tag? Otherwise it is not clear where the `transition` method comes from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some modulo formula to find out whether to turn clockwise or anti-clockwise. Persist the current angle with jQuery's `data` method (so you could have more than one such compass if you wanted to), and allow the angle that you pass as CSS value to be outside the 0-359 range.

Here is how it could work:

```js
function setCompass(degrees){
    var curr = $("#compass").data("rotation") || 0;
    var next = curr + ((degrees - curr)%360 + 180*3) % 360 - 180;
    $("#compass").data("rotation", next).stop().transition({rotate: -next + 'deg'});
}

// Demo with randomly generated angles between 0 and 359
setInterval(function() {
    setCompass(Math.floor(Math.random()*360));
}, 1000);
```

```html
<img id="compass" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdHVn.png" width="100px" height="100px">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.transit/0.9.12/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for fine answer and 1 upvote for random angle simulation.